# Looking for a book series about magicians using strands and the protagonist was the strongest (1990-1998)

Tags: story-identification

I believe in one part in the book he puts out a fire in a tavern. This was apparently very difficult as you need to weave/wield/use many strands (or something) to be able to do that.

This is not Wheel of time.

To be honest, I didn't even read it.  A friend at school used to read it to me (just bits) and I have been looking for it ever since.

Comment: Are you *sure* it's not Wheel of Time?

Comment: [Progeny](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9729882-progeny)?

Comment: [Warbreaker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warbreaker)?

Comment: I suppose it might have been Wheel of time. I was hoping it was something different as I have already read those and thought there might be another epic fantasy series that I could get stuck into. :( –

Answer (score 1):

Possibly Roger Zelazny's [Changeling](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28807.Changeling) or the sequel, Madwand?  I don't remember a tavern fire, but it matches the part about magicians using strands -- at least the protagonist, who was a powerful magician, saw magic that way.

Comment: I suppose it might have been Wheel of time. I was hoping it was something different as I have already read those and thought there might be another epic fantasy series that I could get stuck into. :(

Answer (score 1):

Might it have been the Enchanted Forest Chronicles, by Patricia C Wrede?  In the second book, "[Searching for Dragons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Searching_for_Dragons)", there is a character (Mendanbar) who does magic by reaching for and manipulating the threads of magic local to the area - the area being an enchanted forest, and the various magics of the land interacting to a web.  There is a scene where he restores a burned section of forest by manipulating the strands, something very difficult since it involved a lot of strands at once.

> Carefully, he reached out and gathered a handful of magic. It felt a lot like taking hold of a handful of thin cords, except that the cords were invisible, floating in the air, and made his palms tingle when he touched them. And, of course, each cord was actually a piece of solid magic that he could use to cast a spell if he wanted. In fact, he had to concentrate hard to keep from casting a spell or two with all that magic crammed together in his hands.

It might not be the story you're looking for, especially since the passage I found is of a woods instead of a tavern, specifically, but the description of the strands of magic and manipulating them to cast seemed close enough to be possible.  And it is very quotable, the writing style would translate well to sharing notable quotes or passages that are still funny or absurd even if the recipient hasn't read the book.